# How to un-pivot a dataframe with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, melt

For example, I have a dataframe like this

```
df = {'name':['Jennifer','Vivian','Trisha'],
     'married':[1,1,0],
     'Mon': [0, 0,1],
     'Tu':[1,0,0],
     'Wed':[0,1,0]}
```

[image]

How can I melt the dummy variables into one column like this:

[image]

I tried to use pd.melt() but it just stacks the several columns into one and changes the length of the column. Could someone help me with this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
df.replace({'married':{1:'Married', 0: 'Single'}}). \
   melt(id_vars=['married', 'name'], var_name='Workday'). \
   query('value == 1'). \
   drop('value', axis=1)

#    married      name Workday
# 2   Single    Trisha     Mon
# 3  Married  Jennifer      Tu
# 7  Married    Vivian     Wed
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
res = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['married', 'name'], value_vars=['Mon', 'Tu', 'Wed'],
              var_name='Workday')

res = res[res['value'] == 1].reset_index(drop=True)

d = {0: 'single', 1: 'married'}
res['married'] = res['married'].map(d)

print(res)

#    married      name Workday  value
# 0   single    Trisha     Mon      1
# 1  married  Jennifer      Tu      1
# 2  married    Vivian     Wed      1
```